# Int calculation from byte representation

Tags: binary, type-conversion, hex, byte, twos-complement

Given bytes as HEX: `710e00fe`
I do the following:

```
int value = (*(int*)([bytes bytes]));
int exp = value >> 24; 
int mantissa = value & 0x00FFFFFF;
```

And I get `mantissa = 3697 and exponent = -2`.

I tried doing this manually but I can't figure out how I got those values.
I can actually get the exp right, but mantissa is a huge number when I manually calculate.
Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little-endian CPU.
So, the exponent is the last byte in bytes, i.e. 0xfe == -2 in two's complement.

And the mantissa is 0x000e71, i.e. 3697.